# Does this behavior exist in all major databases?

Tags: sql, comparison, database-agnostic

```
mysql> select 0.121='0.121';
+---------------+
| 0.121='0.121' |
+---------------+
|             1 |
+---------------+
```

Does it hold for other database that `number='number'` is `true`?

Comment: I'd suspect that what's happening is that the number is being converted to a string for the comparison and I'd also suspect that this is pretty common behaviour.

Comment: In most databases, converting numbers to strings is localized. See my answer, I changed it a bit.

Answer (score 6):

First of all: most databases are using **localized number formats**. So turning a number into a string will most probably not always be the same as your hard-coded string.

Then: you will get problems with the sql syntax you use. See my experiments with oracle bellow.

---

In Oracle you always need a FROM clause (except they changed this in version 10).

```
select 0.121='0.121' from sys.dual
```

In Oracle, you can't have an expression like this in the select clause.

You need a case statement:

```
select case when 0.121 = '0.121' then 1 else 0 end as xy 
from sys.dual
```

Then you get an error that it is no number. To fix this, convert it:

```
select case when To_Char(0.121) = '0.121' then 1 else 0 end as xy 
from sys.dual
```

this will return `0`! Because, on my machine, `0.121` is converted to the string `".121"`. These are Swiss settings. If I had German settings, it would be `",121"` (note the comma).

So to finally answer the question: **No**.

Comment: You will get : Error starting at line 1 in command:
select 0.121 = '0,121' from dual
Error at Command Line:1 Column:13
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Answer (score 3):

Even if it does. What does this help you ? 
I would never, ever, make this assumption anyway. You always need to convert both operands to the same type so that, at least, you know what you are comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the reputable databases will do an implicit conversion for this type of query.  There may be published rules for implicit conversions on a particular system - you'd have to look at the vendor coumentation to find out what implicit conversions are done on your system.

For instance, 
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224021(SQL.80).aspx)'s an official reference from Microsoft for SQL Server 2000, and 
[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/craigfr/archive/2008/06/05/implicit-conversions.aspx)'s a blog entry on SQL Server implicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

No.

I don't know why Stackoverflow requires me to enter more than 3 characters in answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

**Postgresql** is a little more strict than **mysql** about [type conversion](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/typeconv.html), and does not let you implicitly cast/convert between numbers and strings. This is sane behaviour, and it is getting slightly more strict with newer versions. Some examples, from Postgres 8.4:

```
db=# select 0.112::float = '0.112'::text;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: double precision = text
LINE 1: select 0.112::float = '0.112'::text;
                            ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

db=# select 0.112 = ('0.1' || '12');
ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric = text
LINE 1: select 0.112 = ('0.1' || '12');
                     ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

db=# select 0.112 = ('0.1' || '12')::float; -- explicit cast
 t
```

However, this example (the original question) works:

```
db=# select 0.122 = '0.122';
 t
```

This is a little surprising (or misleading), given the above. But it has to do with how the query is parsed: when it sees an (unqualified) '0.122' literal, the parser does not necessarily assumes it is of TEXT type, but assigns instead a preliminary "unknown" type; its final type is deduced later by some [heuristics](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/typeconv-overview.html).

Anyway, it's bad practice to rely on this, as mentioned by others.